# In DDD, should any class that is not an Entity or an Value Object be a Service?

Tags: domain-driven-design, naming-conventions, ddd-service

In DDD, should any class that is not an Entity or an Value Object be a Service?

For example, in libraries some classes are named `FileReader` (which read a File object), `Cache` interface that is implemented by `MemcachedCache` or `FileCache`, XXXManager, ...

I understand outside of DDD, you can name your classes however you want to.

But in DDD (and with the same examples), should I name my classes like `FileReadingService`, `CacheService` implemented by `FileCacheService`, `XXXService`, etc ?

Comment: If `FileReader` was part of the domain (which is probably not the case..) you would still call it `FileReader` and not `FileReadingService`. Just like you wouldn't name entities and value objects `ProductEntity` and `AddressValueObject` ;-)

Comment: DDD is about design, not about implementation :]

Comment: @Meta-Knight there is nothing preventing me to prepend "Service" to services? How would you name a "UserService" for example (a service that manages "User" entities)? Why is "UserService" a bad choice?

Comment: @Matthieu: Appending "Service" to every single domain service just makes your names longer and doesn't make them more descriptive. But there is no rule forbidding you to use the word Service when it makes sense to use it... "UserService" is OK, but then isn't it an application service instead of a domain service?

Comment: @Meta-Knight you make a point

Comment: I encapsulate filesystem access for a particular entity within a class called `FileStorageGateway` and consider it to be a type of `Service`. 2c

Answer (score 1):

I think this is really something which is only relevant to your projects naming standards.  DDD does not dictate that level of detail.

My only advice would be to make sure something like `FileReader` is clearly segregated away from you domain. Possibly inside you infrastructure library,

Comment: Well it seems to me like naming everything as an Entity, Value Object or Service makes everything easier and more organized. But is there some downsides to that? Is that a narrow vision, like "[seeing everything as a nail](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail)"

Answer (score 1):

There are additional types of objects in DDD, albeit in a more supporting role than Entity, Service, or ValueObject.  Things like Repositories and Factories spring to mind.  But in general, 'real' objects such as physical objects, or nouns in a problem description, should fall into one of those categories.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i will say YES on that. even though there are other kinds of objects you might encounter but those probably will turn out to be VALUE objects after all. i think of it like this: if it is not an object that needs storing or an object that is managed by an Aggregate root then it must a service managing them.